# Setting constraints with variables as exponents in PySCIPOpt

Tags: scip, exp, pyscipopt

I want to solve an **MINLP problem** with SCIP in Python and therefore use **PySCIPOpt**.
I already introduced the variables, the objective function, and set the constraints (as far as it was possible, given my issue).

Within one constraint, there is a **variable in the exponent of another pair of variables**. Currently, it looks like this (`x_1`, `x_2`, `y_1`, `y_2`, `z`, `v` all are variables):

`model.addCons( x_1 * x_2 * ( (y_1/y_2)**((z-1)/z) -1 )  - v == 0 )`

This gives back the following error:
`NotImplementedError: exponents must be numbers`

I was reading about a builtin `exp()` method, but did not find a good example of how to use it in my specific code.

The only alternative I could imagine would be using the constraint handler, which of course is more work than just putting in `exp()`.

Does anyone has an idea on how to implement the respective constraint in PySCIPOpt?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can directly model constraints with variables in the exponent in SCIP/PySCIPOpt. The documentation states that only constants can be used as exponents: https://scipopt.org/doc/html/group__EXPRHDLRS.php#gaebe772008384fe8ec53cd5e0c8909f9b

Comment: @mattmilten , I know you're involved with PySCIPOpt, do you think my workaround may cause issues?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can model this with PySCIPOpt, by taking into account that

[image: formula]

Which for your exponential yields

[image: formula]

So I think your constraint can then be modeled like this:

`model.addCons( x_1 * x_2 * (exp(((z-1)/z)*log(y_1/y_2))-1) - v == 0 )`

At least the code runs, and if I'm not mistaken, it's mathematically equivalent to what you wanted.